# HTML 5 canvas: detect, if mouse button is pressed while moving mouse over canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I was trying to detect, if mouse is pressed while moving over CANVAS:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (evt) {
           ...
        });
```

Setting a flag inside mousedown and skipping it in mouseup is a bad idea, because user can release mouse button outside the canvas.

Comment: That's still looking more like a hack. Is there some property in evt indicating if mouse button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

`evt.which` will be `1` if left mouse button is held down during the fired mousemove event, `0` if it's not.

Test with:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    console.log(e.which);
});
```

Comment: @user1065145 define not works, as in, link me to a jsfiddle where it's not working

Comment: Been searching for this forever. Does anyone have a solution?